# side menu with UITabBarController and storyboards ios

Tags: xcode, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, menubar

I would like to implement a side menu bar in my application, I have `UITabBarController` and `Storyboard`, I have tried to integrate the menu bar [`MFSideMenu`](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu) , but there is not a menu with `UITabBarController` for storyboard, just for nib files, so I need your help.
Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply do the following:

- Create a `UIStoryboard` instance of the the relevant storyboard you need to set as the center controller, in case you have multiple storyboards. Use `HomeStoryboard` if you have just the standard storyboard in use.
- Instantiate the view controller that is the `initial view controller` of your app, based on it's storyboard ID. You will have to set this in Storyboard (utilities pane).
- Instantiate the view controller you want to use as the left menu.
- Create an instance of `MFSideMenuContainerViewController`, with the center and left(or right, or both) menu controller you just created.
- Set the instance of your `MFSideMenuContainerViewController` as the `rootViewController` of your app window.

Sample code:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"HomeStoryboard" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *homeViewController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeViewController"];

UIViewController* leftMenuViewController = ......//Instantiate your left menu controller

MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                        containerWithCenterViewController:homeViewController
                                                        leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController
                                                        rightMenuViewController:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = container;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: homeViewController could be the UITabController?

Comment: It can be **any** view controller in your storyboard, including `UITabBarController`s. Just make sure you set it's Storyboard ID correctly, and use it in the code.

Comment: can i handle notification with side menu ?

Comment: Too Fast reply @imjaydeep